# oracle sqlplus does not give long result

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sqlplus

I have a simple sql script file which only includes a SELECT statement. But the output of SELECT statement is huge (more than a few hundred thousands lines).

I cannot get output saved in a local file. I just changed my select statement to DESC and it worked fine, so the problem seems the size of output (select statement is something like SELECT * from TABLEX)

I will appreciate any comments on how to execute the select statement..

Thanks in advance

---

I updated my sql script file as below

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
set echo off  
set feedback off  
set linesize 1000  
set pagesize 0  
set sqlprompt ''  
set trimspool on  
set headsep off  

spool output.csv  
select * from JM_WCEL_BTH_CURRENT  
SPOOL OFF  
EXIT
```

The output is below

```
D:\>sqlplus user/user@mydb @2.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Jan 17 10:10:15 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

  4
  5
Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64
bit Production
With the Partitioning, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

D:\>
```

There is nothing in the output file but numbers 4 and 5. I ended the process after a few minutes by pressing Ctrl + C. I also tried removing spooling process, there is no output to console as well.

I tried to run the sql query from ay other tool, it gives results in less than a second!

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you spooling the output to a file?  What error do you get when spooling the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have successfully spooled 60 million rows to csv files using SQL*Plus, using something like this:.

```
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set headsep off

spool output.csv

select 'col1,col2,col3' from dual;

select col1 || ',' || col2 || ',' || col3
from bigtable;

spool off
```

One problem that can happen with very long-running queries is the Oracle session times out, or the TCP connection gets clobbered by a firewall. If your query runs for hours you should probably look into these issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to performance or SQL*Plus limitations.
It is simply missing semicolon at the end of executing command:

```
 select * from JM_WCEL_BTH_CURRENT; 
                                  ^
                                  |____________add semicolon here
```